# como hago para cerrar un menu emergente al darle click a un elemento interno?

Tags: javascript, html, css

'''
este codigo hace el menu y el menu movil este menu es ancla y quiero que cuando le de en #algunelemento se cierre el menu

```
<div class="cabecera-superior">
  <div class="contenedor">
    <h1>URBANSHOUSE</h1>
    <span class="menu-cel">
      <button class="hamburger--elastic" type="button">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
          <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </span>
    <div class="contenedor1" >
este codigo hace el menu y el menu movil este menu es ancla y quiero que cuando le de en #algunelemento se cierre el menu

      <ul class="mostrar">
       <li class="fijo"><a href="#inicio">INICIO</a></li>
       <li class="fijo"><a href="#reproductor"> ESCUCHANOS</a></li>
       <li class="fijo"><a href="#programacion">PROGRAMACIÓN</a></li>
       <li class="fijo"><a href="#acerca-de">QUIENES SOMOS</a></li>
       <li class="fijo"><a href="#contactanos">CONTACTANOS</a></li>


     </ul>
    </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

'''
este codigo hace el menu y el menu movil este menu es ancla y quiero que cuando le de en #algunelemento se cierre el menu

Comment: Existe algo llamado blubbling y capturing,  investiga que es,  de esta manera te daras cuenta como se puede lograr aquello que necesitas,  de hecho es algo basico y un parametro que se encuentra en los eventos oyentes (listeners).

Comment: Por cierto no veo tu javascript por ninguna parte, por lo menos ya intentaste agregarle un evento a tu boton directamente?, puede funcionar sin tener que ponerse a averiguar sobre bubbling y capturing.

Comment: amigo no me subio apenas me doy cuenta pero no tengo pa ese problema como tal tengo pal menu hamburguesa cierre y abra lo normal